# How to compile Linux kernel with multimedia as module on Odroid C2

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

I am trying to compile Linux kernel on Odroid C2 and install DVB-T drivers using [media_build](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers). I followed steps described on the official [wiki](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-c2/software/building_kernel) and [forum](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=20302). According to the forum, it is necessary to make `Device Drivers -> Amlogic Device Drivers -> Multimedia Support` compile as modules if I want to use the backported media_build DVB-T drivers.

First, I obtained Linux source:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/hardkernel/linux.git -b odroidc2-3.14.y
```

Then I set the configuration for Odroid C2:

```
make odroidc2_defconfig
```

And finally, I followed the steps for kernel compilation and disabled V4L dependencies as follows:

```
$make menuconfig
Device Drivers
    Amlogic Device Drivers
  ION Support
     ION memory management support = no
  Amlogic ion video support
     videobuf2-ion video device support = no
     Amlogic ion video devic support = no
  V4L2 Video Support
     Amlogic v4l video device support = no
     Amlogic v4l video2 device support = no
  Amlogic Camera Support
     Amlogic Platform Capture Driver = no
  Multimedia support = m
```

This configuration compiles without errors, and then I can compile and install media_build drivers. The problem is that with this configuration, Odroid C2 is not capable of playing video files in Kodi with hardware decoding. My impression is that I disabled a dependency which is necessary for amlogic hardware decoding. I tried to modify the config and marked as modules all the dependencies which I previously disabled. Unfortunately, with this configuration, the kernel could not be compiled, and the compilation failed with following error:

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `v4l2_device_release':
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x1731c0): undefined reference to 
`media_device_unregister_entity'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x1731c0): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `media_device_unregister_entity'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `__video_register_device':
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x173c4c): undefined reference to 
`media_device_register_entity'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x173c4c): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `media_device_register_entity'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `v4l2_device_register_subdev':
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x1797b0): undefined reference to 
`media_device_register_entity'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x1797b0): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `media_device_register_entity'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `v4l2_device_unregister_subdev':
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x179a58): undefined reference to 
`media_entity_remove_links'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x179a58): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `media_entity_remove_links'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x179a60): undefined reference to 
`media_device_unregister_entity'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x179a60): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `media_device_unregister_entity'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `subdev_close':
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x180c10): undefined reference to `media_entity_put'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x180c10): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `media_entity_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `subdev_open':
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x1814f4): undefined reference to `media_entity_get'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x1814f4): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `media_entity_get'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x181540): undefined reference to `media_entity_put'
odroid-battery.c:(.text+0x181540): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `media_entity_put'
Makefile:831: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

How can I compile the kernel with Multimedia Support as modules and still be able to use hardware decoding for video files?

Comment: When you tried to restore the dependencies as modules, did you use `make menuconfig` again, or did you edit the configuration file directly?

Comment: I used `make menuconfig` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally make it work. I created a git repository with a script, patches, and instructions. If someone is also dealing with this issue please clone [this repository](https://github.com/pichljan/odroidC2-kernel) and do the following steps (these are also described in the README in the repository):

**Linux**

Clone Hardkernel Linux repository

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/hardkernel/linux.git -b odroidc2-3.14.y
cd linux
```

Apply patch which allows you to compile aml video driver as a module (I took this step from [LibreELEC media_build edition](https://github.com/wrxtasy/LibreELEC.tv))

```
patch -p1 < ../odroidC2-kernel/allow_amlvideodri_as_module.patch
```

Apply default Odroid C2 config

```
make odroidc2_defconfig
```

Now modify the config

```
make menuconfig
```

And set the following values (press Y to select, N to remove and M to select it as a module)

```
Device Drivers
   Amlogic Device Drivers
      ION Support
         ION memory management support = Yes
      Amlogic ion video support
         videobuf2-ion video device support = M
         Amlogic ion video devic support = no
      V4L2 Video Support
         Amlogic v4l video device support = M
         Amlogic v4l video2 device support = no
      Amlogic Camera Support
         Amlogic Platform Capture Driver = no
   Multimedia support = M
```

Compile the kernel

```
make -j5 LOCALVERSION=""
```

The LOCALVERSION parameter is only to avoid "+" sign in the name of the kernel.
After the successful compilation, install the modules, kernel and reboot the system

```
sudo make modules_install
sudo cp -f arch/arm64/boot/Image arch/arm64/boot/dts/meson64_odroidc2.dtb /media/boot/
sudo sync
sudo reboot
```

**Media build**

Clone media_build repository and try to build it.

```
git clone https://git.linuxtv.org/media_build.git
cd media_build
./build
```

The build command probably fails. Ignore this error and continue with following steps.
Following script is also inspired by [LibreELEC media_build edition](https://github.com/wrxtasy/LibreELEC.tv) and it just includes the video driver into media module.

```
../odroidC2-kernel/add_video_driver_module.sh
```

To avoid potential issues with compilation, try to disable Remote controller support and all the USB adapter you don't need to.
Try to run:

```
make menuconfig
```

It will probably result in an error similar to the following one:

```
./Kconfig:694: syntax error
./Kconfig:693: unknown option "Enable"
./Kconfig:694: unknown option "which"
```

You need to edit the file `v4l/Kconfig` and align with spaces the lines printed in the error. The lines need to be aligned with the previous ones. Then, run the `make menuconfig` again. Probably, you need to do this step multiple times.

If you see a menu instead of the error, you can modify the config in the following way:

```
Remote Controller support = no
Multimedia support
    Media USB Adapters
        ## Disable all driver you don't need ##
```

Apply the following patch

```
patch -p1 < ../odroidC2-kernel/warning.patch
```

Make the following change to avoid error and compile kernel

```
sed -i 's/#define NEED_PM_RUNTIME_GET 1/\/\/#define NEED_PM_RUNTIME_GET 1/g' v4l/config-compat.h
make -j5
```

Possibly, you need to run previous step (both sed and make) multiple times before it succeeds.

After the compilation, install the modules and reboot the system

```
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

The final step is to add `amlvideodri` module into `/etc/modules` to make it load on boot.

```
sudo echo "amlvideodri" >> /etc/modules
```

That's all. You can now enjoy your DVB-T TV and HW accelerated videos in Kodi.